# Is there any plugin for wordpress page pagination by category?

Tags: wordpress

Is there any plugin in wordpress for pagination by category?

For example: In my site, there are 10 categories and each category has 20 pages. I want to make pagination by category. I iwant to show 20 pages in one category by pagination(like 1 2 3...20).

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use tabs component from [Visual Composer](https://visualcomposer.io/download/)  and inside each tab use post by category component, that is how you can have a pagination by posts.